# Symbian C++ Development Under Mac OS X

Tags: c++, symbian, nokia, carbide

I've been developing for Symbian S60 3rd Edition since last year using [Carbide.c++](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/dbb8841d-832c-43a6-be13-f78119a2b4cb.html) under Windows. THe problem is that I moved to Mac OS X this year(bought a Macbook Pro) and when I was going to download Carbide.c++, I saw that it's Windows-only, because of the Requirements:

> Microsoft Windows XP Professional Service Pack 2 or Microsoft Windows Vista (32-bit).
>   1 GB of RAM.
>   700 MB of free disk space for Carbide.c++.
>   1.8-GHz processor; x86 architecture.
>   ActiveState ActivePerl-5.6.1.635.
>   At least one Symbian OS platform SDK.
>   1,024 x 768-pixel screen capable of displaying 16-bit colour.

But there are any alternatives for Mac OS X?

Comment: where is a port: http://www.martin.st/symbian/ this might help!

Comment: You can always set up a Windows VM on your Mac and use that. VMware Fusion, Parallels, Boot Camp, Virtual Box, etc.

Comment: I was thinking on something like an IDE, since I'm pretty used to it. Also I'm not interested in emulating Windows

Comment: I've the same situation: I shifted over to Mac for engineering, but I still have to carry my Windows PC for Symbian development. I tried using virtual machine, but if you want to develop something serious, it becomes extremely slow...the build takes forever, the simulator is very slow to start up, and stepping-over while debugging is painfully slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, Mac is not officially supported *if* you want to develop apps for Symbian (either using QT or without QT). The problem is that all the tools needed to create the final binary run only on Windows (abld).

[This page](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Qt_for_Symbian_Developers_Library/GUID-7E53D0F7-72CB-41C4-8807-FE7A772B0DB4.html) on Forum Nokia makes it pretty clear:

Qt for Symbian development requirements
    In order to develop Qt applications for Symbian devices you'll need the following setup:

1. Development PC. 
         You need a Windows PC. At present, Symbian development is best supported on Windows XP and Windows Vista.

You can use remote compiler from mac via qt.
http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/01/20/qt-sdk-1-1-technology-preview-released/

Answer (score 2):

> But there are any alternatives for Mac OS X?

One alternative is to use QT Creator on Mac to develop your Symbian app. You can develop and debug it for SImulator versions only on Mac, so once you're done developing/testing it on Mac, you can transfer your project/synch with your s/w versioning tool on Windows for actual on-target debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Qt for MacOs from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-mac-os-cpp. Nokia is strongly urging (standardizing on) Qt for new development. Stay tuned for the Nokia Investor Strategy and Financial Briefing on Feb. 11.

Answer (score 0):

running Symbian emulator in VMWare never worked 100% for me... If the Qt is enough for you you can use QtCreator - it is available also for MAC OS.

BR
STeN